# When you are indebted to someone and want to return their favor

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

All of us are well aware that most of the people are indebted to their parents because of their efforts in our lives. I would appreciate it if someone could let me know which one of the following sentences sounds more natural to explain what I said in a natural way:

> - We can never return the big favor our parents did for us.
> - We can never settle the debt we hold with our parents.
> - The debt we owe our parents can never be paid back.

For me, the last one is not as good as the first two sentences which mean exactly the same.

I guess they all are grammatically, structurally and idiomatically correct, but I doubted if a native speaker would say it in a different and better manner.

P.S. [All of the above sentences are self-made.]

Comment: To me, the last sounds the most natural and most emotionally impactful.

Comment: Your sentences are *always* "self-made". I think you should trademark that expression. I've given up suggesting you use a dictionary to see how a term is used, and Googling short expressions such as  *return the big favor* would tell you how idiomatic they are. Sometimes you get so close, I wonder if you do it deliberately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's funny you feel that the last sentence is not as good as the first two, because to me it seems exactly the opposite - the last sentence reads to me as being the most natural of the three.

All three, as you say, are grammatically correct, so my reasoning is subjective to a degree, but taking the first example:

> We can never return the **big favor** our parents did for us.

*favour* to me very much understates the situation. When someone does me a favour, they've imparted on me an act of kindness - perhaps they've loaned me something, or covered for me at work. I wouldn't however, equate it to raising and providing for me.

In the second example:

> We can never settle the **debt we hold** with our parents.

...the usage of **hold a debt** is incorrect. If somebody holds a debt, it means they are **owed** something, not that they **owe** something to another person. In this case, the parents are the debt holders, not us, as your sentence states.

One could correct the sentence by rephrasing it to:

> We can never settle the debt we **owe to** our parents.

...which seems a little formal, but it gets the point across.

The third example:

> The debt we owe our parents can never be paid back.

reads far more naturally to me. Personally, I might rearrange it slightly to read:

> - We can never pay back the debt we owe to our parents.
>
> *or simply:*
>
> - We can never our my parents back for everything they've done for us.

...but that's more a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

## "Forever indebted..."

...is a phrase often used to indicated the idea(s) expressed in the OP.

> We are forever indebted to our parents for their [support | kindness | love | guidance, etc.]